# store value to global variable from the foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, addeventlistener

I am trying to store value in the global variable then pass it through Axios, but I can't store it in the variable. here is my code sample.

```
const voteSubmit = document.querySelector('#voteSubmit');
const votevalue = document.querySelectorAll('.votting_buttons button');

let voteNum;
votevalue.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        voteNum = btn.dataset.votno;
    });
});
```

how could I store it?

Comment: Add whole code...

Comment: this is the only js part I don't have more code. @Danial

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ your code

Comment: Your variable won't be updated until the user clicks one of the buttons. Since you haven't shown the code that tries to use the value, I can only assume that you're trying to use it before a button has been clicked.

Comment: I am trying to get the button value on click and store it in a global variable, then pass it through Axios. and store into the database.  @RichardDeeming

Comment: @freelanceingmindset But you haven't shown any of the code that passes the value through Axios, and you told Daniel that you don't have any other code. Either there's a problem with the code you haven't shown, or you haven't written the code you've just described yet.

Comment: actual I am planning like this but still, I did not write Axios code, I just start and stack with store value in the global variable. @RichardDeeming

Comment: @freelanceingmindset You've already written the code to store the value in the variable. It sounds like your question is actually *"write the Axios code for me"*?

Comment: I want to store the vote value in this  `let voteNum;` from the EventListener that's it.  I could Handel the Axios part.  @RichardDeeming

Comment: @freelanceingmindset But you've already done that! `voteNum = btn.dataset.votno;` will take the `data-votno` from the clicked button and store it in the `voteNum` variable. So what is the question?

Comment: when I `console log` the `voteNum ` inside the addEventListener it's showing the value. but when I try to check it outside global `voteNum ` then undefine showing. that is the problem.  @RichardDeeming

Comment: @freelanceingmindset And as I said previously, the variable **will not be set** until one of the buttons has been clicked. If you try to log the value of the variable before a button has been clicked, it will not have been set.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. it's valuable info for me. just solve the issue by taking your info. @RichardDeeming